# Every time restart Lubuntu terminal unable to init server, cannot open display

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, gnome-terminal, sddm

I did something related to ssh or display setting which I don't understand, now every time I restart the Lubuntu, terminal cannot open graphical application:

```
chen@jesuslovesme:~$ gedit
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.gedit:4921): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:52:41.435: cannot open display: localhost:0
chen@jesuslovesme:~$ echo $DISPLAY   
localhost:0
```

If I run

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

the problems can temparely solved. Restart the computer return to the same problem

Comment: It would be great if you recalled what you did. If you followed an online tutorial, please [edit] your question and add a link to it. In the meantime, take a look at your `.bashrc` file. Maybe there's a line that sets the `DISPLAY` variable to `localhost:0`.

Comment: thank you very much @danzel I `ll -thr .bashrc` found yesterday was edited, I don't remmember however. I comment out the line `export DISPLAY=localhost:0`, returns normal, why not change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to the comment above, solution is such

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

comment out

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```