# gedit error - "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused"

Tags: gedit

when I type `gedit ~/.bashrc`
I get this error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:204): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:03:28.442: cannot open display
```

can anyone tell me what the problem is please

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the release and flavor of Ubuntu. If possible, provide the steps to reproduce the issue. If you suspect you might have made some mistake that caused the issue, please describe it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every time restart Lubuntu terminal unable to init server, cannot open display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223694/every-time-restart-lubuntu-terminal-unable-to-init-server-cannot-open-display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gedit is trying to run a grahpical application and to run those applications, you need an X server like [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) or [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/).
So i'd install one of those.
Close your cmd or terminal and launch the X server.
Open your cmd and set the DISPLAY, like: `export DISPLAY=0:0` and run that gedit command again.

This works for most people.